# How to make an SQL for this: an integral field and it's last four must be zero

Tags: mysql

ex: `1230000` is OK, `1230001` isn't OK.

Comment: Your question is far from clear. Do you mean a check constraint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT column WHERE column % 1000 = 0
```